# Wordpress: subcategory is subtracted from slug if parent category is checked

Tags: wordpress, slug

I have the following category hierarchy:

```
-Cat
--SubCat
---SubSubCat
```

When creating an post and mark it only in the `subsubcat` category, the correct slug is generated: `www.example.com/cat/subcat/subsubcat/post-title`

When creating an post and mark it in the `subcat` and `subsubcat` categories, the slug is generated by subtracting the grandchild category:
`www.example.com/cat/subcat/post-title`

This is the normal operation of Wordpress or would it be a bug?

My permalink configuration is custom structure:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This [article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-include-category-and-subcategory-in-wordpress-urls/) describes the behavior of Wordpress with respect to categories, sub-categories, and sub-sub-categories.

According to them,

> Another scenario is when you have a parent category, subcategory, and a sub-subcategory. WordPress will include all three of them in the URL.
>
> http://example.com/apple/technology/events/article-title-here/

So you should be able to see all categories correctly nested. Check that you've configured your slug generation correctly. Also, check with [Wordpress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The slug is set correctly, as per the image I added now. Only include the 3 in the url if only `subsubcat` is checked (leaving the `cat` and `subcat` boxes unchecked). The problem is, I'm displaying related posts by category and I need to check the parent category to display them.

Comment: That sounds like a related post plugin issue more so now... Are you using Jetpack or a dedicated plugin?

Comment: Not! I only use 6 plugins (Akismet Anti-Spam, Google XML Sitemaps, AMP, Classic Editor, KK Star Ratings, and WP Fatest Cache).

Comment: Strangely enough, the `subsubcat` is only subtracted from the slug that is generated on the classic editor screen when we publish or update the post. But on the homepage the links are complete.

Comment: It might well be that multiple links are valid. It's worth filing a bug with wpress directly

Comment: Thanks for pointing the way
I'll register the bug and as soon as you have answer I'll be back to update.